# Plotting function of 2D space + time using Plot3D in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a simple way of plotting a function *f(x,y,t) = Exp[t-x-y]* by setting the time *t*? I've tried several variations of

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[f[t,x,y],t->0],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},PlotRange -> All]
```

But I can't get it to work. I want to be able to change *t* and see how the plot changes, but I'm also using the equation *f* for a differential equation so I'm taking partials and I need *t* to be symbolic for other parts of the notebook. Or is there a way to make a plot video that updates with time?

Comment: It isn't a movie, but will this do? `Plot3D[Table[f[x,y,t],{t,0,3,1/4}],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},PlotRange->All]`

Comment: Interesting, thank you for providing that solution, it's very helpful.The only thing I changed is instead of writing *f[x,y,t]*, I only need to write f. This plots the data at the different time points all on the same plot, and I'm going to work on see if there's an easy way to divide into multiple plots. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the comments.

Interactively manipulate the plot

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := Sin[t x] Sin[t y]
Manipulate[Plot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, -Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}], {t, 0, 3, 1/8}]
```

Generate a list of plots

```
plots = Table[Plot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, -Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}], {t, 0, 3, 1/8}];
```

Export the plots to an animated GIF

```
Export["plots.gif", plots]
```

[image]